# Writing a library in unix

Tags: unix, task-parallel-library, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I have to do this:

Write a library responsible for handling an array array with pointers to blocks containing the results of the execution of the find command. Following instructions are possible:

- execute search of the files with the name filenames starting from root directory, store the output and diagnostic output in temp file. You can use system function to execute the external proces/Unix command – Syntax: search root filenames temp
- store the content of the temp file in dynamically allocated block of memory, add the pointer to this block in the array – store temp
- remove (dealocate) the block of memory accessed in the entry number in array – remove number.

But I don't know how to start. Does anyone know where I can find info or can help me to do this?

Comment: You didn't really mean to write _an array array_, did you?

Comment: no, just an array

Comment: Then you'd have to edit and correct that.